# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'login' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` () values ())

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am doing registration on my new project on Laravel and getting an error 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'login' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` () values ())
Here is my code.
View:

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<h1>Регистрация</h1>

<form action="/user/" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="login">Login</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password-repeat">Repeat password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password-repeat" name="password-repeat">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Регистрация</button>
</form>

@stop
```

Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $userConstuctor['login'] = Request::input('login');
    $userConstuctor['password'] = Request::input('password');
    $user = new User($userConstuctor);
    $user->setUser(Request::all());
    $user->save();
}
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Session;

class User extends Model
{
const ADMIN = 1;
const MANAGER = 2;
const USER = 3;

public $login;
public $password;
private $email;
private $firstName;
private $secondName;
private $lastName;
private $avatar;
private $userOptions = [];
private $createdDate;
private $rememberToken;
private $active;
private $groupId;
public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable = ['login', 'password', 'email', 'created_date', 'remember_token', 'active', 'group_id'];
protected $table = 'users';

public function __construct($userConstuctor)
{
    $this->setLogin($userConstuctor['login']);
    $this->setPassword($userConstuctor['password']);
}

public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->setEmail($user['email']);
    $this->setCreatedDate();
    $this->setRememberToken($user['_token']);
    $this->setActive();
    $this->setGroupId();
}

private function setLogin($login)
{
    $this->login = $login;
}

private function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = md5($password);
}

private function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

private function setCreatedDate()
{
    $this->createdDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

private function setRememberToken($token)
{
    $this->rememberToken = $token;
}

private function setActive()
{
    $this->active = false;
}

private function setGroupId()
{
    $this->groupId = self::USER;
}

}
```

Table Schema:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('login')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('second_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('avatar', 250)->nullable();
        $table->longText('user_options')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('created_date');
        $table->boolean('active');
        $table->rememberToken('token');
        $table->integer('group_id');
    });
```

The response I got from `dd()` :-
http://joxi.net/823WMQ4f647LX2

Comment: how you are calling `create` method ? share routes as well ?

Comment: var_dump(Request::input('login')) shows me: string(5) "romka"
Sorry, I don't know how to put here so much code, so I've made a picture of dd($user) before I try to save it
http://joxi.ru/823WMQ4f647LX2

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your query got nothing to insert in table
Also, I need to know do you need to create user from more then one controller?

Try this

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $userConstuctor['login'] = $request->login;
    $userConstuctor['password'] = $request->password;
    $user = new User();
    $user->login = $request->login;
    $user->password = $request->password;
 /*and so on....*/
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but I still have the same error
I wanted to create user from one controller and create admins and managers from another

Comment: if it doesn't effect you much and it is not necessary to use function like setUser() and all you can follow the simple and straight approach like I have edited in my answer